can anyone tell me why i am getting this error when i trying to create a token
i am getting this error
Error in create mint Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import * as token from "@solana/spl-token";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { useState } from "react";

const CreateMint = () => {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
  const [minttoken, setMintToken] = useState<web3.PublicKey>();

  async function createMint() {
    if (!publicKey) return;
    const payer = web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log("Payer:", payer.publicKey.toString());
    const lamports = await token.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);
    const transaction = new web3.Transaction();
    const instruction = web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      toPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      lamports,
    });
    transaction.add(instruction);
    const sign = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
    console.log("sol transfered from your wallet to payer account", sign);

    
       try {
        const Token = await token.createMint( //getting error in this line
            connection,
            payer,
            payer.publicKey,
            payer.publicKey,
            2,
          );
          console.log( `Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${Token}?cluster=devnet`)
          setMintToken(Token);
       } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in create mint", error);
       }
    }

  return (
    <div className=" w-fit mx-auto mt-4">
      {publicKey ? (
        <button className="bg-white text-black px-4 py-2 rounded-xl font-bold"
        onClick={createMint}>
          Create Mint
        </button>
      ) : null}
      <div>
        {minttoken ? (
          <div>
            <div className="text-xl">Mint Token Address:</div>
            <a
              className="text-blue-500"
              href={`https://explorer.solana.com/address/${minttoken}?cluster=devnet`}
              target="_blank"
            >
              {minttoken?.toString()}
            </a>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateMint;


0x1 is insufficient funds, you transferred enough for the mint's rent but not for the tx fee to send the createAccount and createInitializeMint ixes.

found my mistake i was only crediting the minimum amount needed to create token but forgot about the gas fee so added little more lamports to the amount to be credited and it worked
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import * as token from "@solana/spl-token";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { useState } from "react";

const CreateMint = () => {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
  const [minttoken, setMintToken] = useState<web3.PublicKey>();

  async function createMint() {
    if (!publicKey) return;
    const payer = web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log("Payer:", payer.publicKey.toString());
    const lamports = await token.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection)+10000;//here added some extra for gas fee
    const transaction = new web3.Transaction();
    const instruction = web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      toPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      lamports,
    });
    transaction.add(instruction);
    const sign = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
    console.log("sol transfered from your wallet to payer account", sign);

    setTimeout(async()=>{ //added set timeout to just wait for the above transaction to settle
       try {
        const Token = await token.createMint(
            connection,
            payer,
            payer.publicKey,
            payer.publicKey,
            2,
          );
          console.log( `Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${Token}?cluster=devnet`)
          setMintToken(Token);
       } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in create mint", error);
       }
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div className=" w-fit mx-auto mt-4">
      {publicKey ? (
        <button className="bg-white text-black px-4 py-2 rounded-xl font-bold"
        onClick={createMint}>
          Create Mint
        </button>
      ) : null}
      <div>
        {minttoken ? (
          <div>
            <div className="text-xl">Mint Token Address:</div>
            <a
              className="text-blue-500"
              href={`https://explorer.solana.com/address/${minttoken}?cluster=devnet`}
              target="_blank"
            >
              {minttoken?.toString()}
            </a>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateMint;

